# What is the significance of the Ravager Flames?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

In Guardians of the Galaxy, Vol. 2, a flame symbolizes the ravagers.   You may recall that.

> Yondu gives a metal flame emblem to Groot and asks Groot to match it to the metal emblem on one of his drawers.

Here is a picture of it:

[image].

> **The flame symbol seems to be their emblem. What is its history? And what is its significance?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That flame insignia comes from the costume of Star-Lord in the comics, dating back to the character's original appearance.

[image: closeup of Star-Lord's flame insignia]

It later became a more prominent part of his outfit during the Annihilation event, when the character was revitalized.

[image]

Presumably, then, when designing the costumes for the movie and creating the backstory for the movie versions of the characters, it was decided to use the insignia as the Ravagers' own.

As for any in-universe history of the insignia... I dunno.

Answer (score 4):

**It would seem that this badge was created to represent the Marvel Cinematic Universe's (Earth-199999) Ravagers.**

As such, we will have no clue of the badge's significance until MCU's directors sheds some light onto it. Before the release of GotG Vol. 2, director James Gunn posts [this](https://www.instagram.com/p/BCOWYS5IzXL/).

Also, here is an [interview](https://www.wheretowatch.com/2014/08/costume-designer-alexandra-byrne-on-gearing-up-the-guardians) with GotG's costume designer:

> Q: Yondu has a similarly cool look, which seemed to me like part biker, part bounty hunter. How did you devise his look, as well as his gang’s?
>
> A: I wanted the Ravagers to have a distinct look—a coat type silhouette and a through line of color. But within that I also wanted them to be individuals with personalized looks. Yondu is the leader, the top dog, and a collector. **Within all the Ravagers there are five generations of the ravager garb/uniform—all personalized, adapted and repaired. When the Guardians dress for the final battle they are wearing the latest Ravager garb**.

[image: GotG Vol.1 Ravagers]